# Hibernate persist error, id field is null

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

Hi im trying to do a persist but looks like if one of the atributes never was set but, just before do the persist I print the value and is set. I´m working with postgrest

My persist metod

```
  public void saveText(Document document){

    sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    System.out.println(document.getText());
    System.out.println(document.getId());

    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(document);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
}
```

My object to pesist

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import br.com.symsar.sysged.acessobd.AccesData;

@Entity
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
@Table(name = "documents", schema = "public")
public class Document implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "\"id\"")
private int id;
@Column(name = "\"text\"")
private String text;

public void persist() {
    AccesData access = new AccesData();
    access.saveText(this);
}

/**
 * @return the text
 */
public String getText() {
    return text;
}

/**
 * @param text
 *            the text to set
 */
public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

Sql query showed by hibernate

```
Hibernate: insert into public.documents ("id", "text") values (null, ?)
```

This is the error:

```
ERROR: ERRO: Null value in the column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

Comment: Hibernate version? What if you use the a `@SequenceGenerator` and `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`?

Comment: Could you had the table definition for your Document entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved not using session factory now I´m using entity manager, when I made this change works.
Thanks all for the ideas

Answer (score 1):

Field `id` have JPA annotation `@Id` in your entity class. It's mean's that it can't be `null`. Try insert value without id parameter:

```
Hibernate: insert into public.documents ("text") values (?)
```

Comment: and you can write just "id", "text" in name attribute

Comment: I need the id column, actually that parameter have a generation id strategy, because I must have an id in my table. If i do that. I get this erro: `No identifier specified for entity`

Comment: Also in postgresql autoincrement values should have type bigserial

Comment: I already altered this field as big serial whith this instruction `ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN key_column BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY;`
But still doesn´t works. Any ideas?

Comment: Then try set next `GenerationType`  `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing annotations 
@ManagedBean 
@SessionScoped